# Using javascript how can I loop through regex matches and split string into array of pieces divided by hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, regex

I have a string that I retrieved from an api that looks like this:

```
"If you <a href='https://example.com'>Click here</a> then <a href='https://example.net'>Click here</a>."
```

I'm trying to create an array that looks like this:

```
[
 "If you "
 <a ... </a>
 " then "
 <a ... </a>
 "."
]
```

Basically I want to render it as it was intended to be without just using dangerously set innerHtml approach.
I already have my regex matches I'm just trying to figure out the smartest way to loop over them and build this.  I just typed this up but realized after seeing the output that its obviously flawed, I need to know where to start my substring based on the last match but can't seem to sort out how to approach this.  Any guidance appreciated

```
  let noticeTextArr: (string | JSX.Element)[] = [];
  if(notice.label !== undefined) {
    const reg = /<a.+?href="(.+?)".*?>(.+?)<\/a>/g;
    let result;
    while((result = reg.exec(notice.label)) !== null) {
      if(result.index > 0) {
        noticeTextArr.push(notice.label.substring(0, result.index))
      }
      noticeTextArr.push(<a href={result[1]}>{result[2]}</a>);      
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can split string using split then loop over the array. if string equal to "<a>" then wait till you receive </a>. you can create a variable res to store the data. Once you detect the <a> then push res variable data into array. start a while loop till you will not get </a>. Append the data in array.

Comment: I can't just split the string because I can't actually trust whats in the string, so I use regular expression to find the matches and manually build the anchor tags.

Comment: if you do not trust the source of the content, then just extracting the link and re creating them will not make it safer, unless you somehow validate the actual `href` contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little bit creepy but quite well-working regex. It's basically the same approach that you did with enhancements.

```
function convertToJSX(text: string) {
  const regex = /<\s*a[^>]*href=["']([^>]*)["'][^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*a>/g;

  const matches = text.matchAll(regex);

  const noticeTextArr: (string | JSX.Element)[] = [];

  let lastIndex = 0;

  for (const match of matches) {
    const [fullMatch, href, content] = match;

    noticeTextArr.push(text.substring(lastIndex, match.index));
    noticeTextArr.push(<a href={href}>{content}</a>);

    lastIndex = match.index + fullMatch.length;
  }

  if (lastIndex < text.length) {
    noticeTextArr.push(text.substring(lastIndex));
  }

  return noticeTextArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const text = "If you <a href='https://example.com'>Click here</a> then <a href='https://example.net'>Click here</a>.";

const array = text.split(/(<a.+?href=["'].+?["'].*?>.+?<\/a>)/g);
```

When you split with your regex as a whole group, js split the text returning also the captured groups. So I have changed the regex to removed the inner groups.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = "If you <a href='https://example.com'>Click here</a> then <a href='https://example.net'>Click here</a>."


const c = data.split(' ')
let i = 0
let res = ''
let arr = []
while(i< c.length){
    if(c[i] === '<a') {
        arr.push(res)
        res = c[i]
        i++;
        while(!c[i].includes('</a>')) {
          res += " "+c[i]
          i++
        } 
        res += " "+c[i++]
        arr.push(res)
        res ='';
     } else {
         res +=" "+ c[i++]
     }
  }  
  console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` with a regular expression having capturing group:

```js
const text = "If you <a href='https://example.com'>Click here</a> then <a href='https://example.net'>Click here</a>.";
console.log(text.split(/(<a\s[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>)/));
```

[See how the regex works](https://regex101.com/r/67sEvZ/1)

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <a                       '<a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^<]*                    any character except: '<' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a>                       'a>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's hard to parse an html element, I would suggest to use [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) in order to let the browser to parse and split your text:

```js
var txt = "If you <a href='https://example.com'>Click here</a> then <a href='https://example.net'>Click here</a>.";
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = txt;
var result = Array.from(el.querySelector('body').childNodes).map(function(ele) {
    return ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ? ele.textContent : ele.outerHTML;
});

console.log(result);
```